# PrimeNG Table get filtered row

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using PrimeNG 6.0.2 with Angular 5 and I'm having issues with the **Table** plugin. I switched to Table because DataTable is deprecated. Now, I can't access filtered values the way I could before.

Let's say I define my table in component via ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('myTable') dataTable: Table;
```

With DataTable, I could just access the *_value* property which held sorted and filtered data:

```
dataTable._value[index] = ...;
```

But now, this property hold just the sorted array, while I have to use the *filteredValue* property:

```
dataTable.filteredValue[index] = ...;
```

My problem with this is that the *filteredValue* is `undefined` before any filtering, has value when the table is filtered and is `null` after I remove all filter text. This yields some pretty ugly code.

Is it possible to access the current data, be it sorted, filtered or identical to the starting array? Or do I have to go with this approach?

Answer (score 15):

Another way you can access the filtered values is by declaring the `onFilter` event and then retrieve/store the filtered values.

```js
// on your component class declare
onFilter(event, dt) { 
  this.filteredValues = event.filteredValue; 
}
```

```html
<p-table #dt .... (onFilter)="onFilter($event, dt)">
```

Comment: Tested with version 12.1.0 and it worked

Answer (score 6):

I know this is quite a late answer but for anyone else having this problem, you can just use the `table.hasFilter()` function on the table itself and decide based on that which property to access. Results in quite some overhead as well but to me it feels a lot cleaner than doing `!!table.filteredValue`.